# Measuring the accuracy of a news article by the number of proven statements

Tags: bayesian, standard-deviation, standard-error, accuracy, weighted-regression

I'm currently developing an app which aggregates news and highlights objective statements and facts from it. This then puts them to vote by the public. Firstly, someone must cite the fact elsewhere to either prove, or disprove it. Then other members are allowed to vote this citation up or down to support it. Multiple citations can be made for each article and each article can (and almost always will) have multiple facts.

I want to show a score of how accurate each article is in order for users to see the most accurate articles, but I'm not sure what the best method will be. If I allow it to be 100% as soon as the first positive citation is entered; or 0% for the first negative, then it will skew the articles initially. The chances are the majority of articles will be 60-100% accurate, so it needs to reflect this early on. Is there a good method that could be used, I imagine some form of weighting will be essential, perhaps some form of standard deviation or Bayesian approach?

Any help would be much appreciated.